# Using both Ctrl+Alt to replace AltGr 3rd level function on xorg

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout

On Windows, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd> is mapped to <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>, but not so on Linux.

Using <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> for 3rd level keys is wrist-killer! I'm unable to find a workaround that doesn't remove other functionality I use (the few mapping options in keyboard settings). I found references for others with the same problems (plenty of Europeans..), but I haven't found a single acceptable workaround.

Has anyone found a way to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd> to <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>?

BTW: I've mapped left <kbd>Alt</kbd> for 3rd level keys, and disabled <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> (which makes <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> behave like regular <kbd>Alt</kbd>). This works, but it makes switching between Windows and Linux (or other workstations) a lot harder.

Comment: What do you mean by *3rd level* keys? Do you mean characters in the shift state activated by AltGr?

Comment: Do you mean in X11 or on the Linux virtual console?

Comment: @pilona: X11, but the question is two years old. I'm now using programmer dvorak, so this is no longer an issue for me.

Comment: @simendsjo What about question in my comment?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost I'm not familiar with the terminology you use. The keys have 3 symbols on them. One is default when pressing it, one is enabled using shift, and one enabled using altgr. IIRC, there are 5 levels you can access in total. As noted above, I'm now using programmer dvorak, and I've bound a key as the composite key so I can also type "special" characters like æøå.

Answer (score 2):

I think creating an XKB keyboard type with `map[Control+Alt] = Level3;` should do it. Credit to William Hatch at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157834/how-to-bind-altgr-to-ctrl-alt

```
type "Level3withCtrlAlt" {
  modifiers = Control+Alt+Shift;
  map[None] = Level1;
  map[Shift] = Level2;
  map[Control+Alt] = Level3;
  map[Control+Alt+Shift] = Level4;
};
```